# How to use XPath to select following-sibling?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

```
<tr>
  <td width="120" align="right" class="tit">application date：</td>
  <td><span style="text-decoration: underline;color: #0066ff;cursor: pointer"  
       onclick="_search('ad','2016.01.18');">2016.01.18</span></td>
</tr>
```

How can I use XPath to get the date value "2016.01.18" ?  The dates after "ad" are different.

Comment: Why do you need to use XPath? Can simple Javascript/DOM code do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following XPath-1.0 expression to select the following `<span>` of the `<td>` which contains `application date`:

```
//td[contains(text(),'application date')]/following-sibling::td[1]/span
```

Output is:

> 2016.01.18

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//td[normalize-space()='application date:']/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text()
```

will return

```
2016.01.18
```

as requested.